# How to close an Angular2 modal with a boolean?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I'm new to html and Angular2. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

I am placing a form component inside a ng2-modal and I would like the modal to close when the form returns a boolean from an event.

The form is for adding a new class to a database. Its first usage is on another page where it is not inside a modal. 
There, upon clicking cancel/submit in the component, I have it return `true` and then redirect to another url.

For the new implementation I want the modal to close when the form returns `true`. The problem is that the save/cancel buttons are in the component containing the form. So I can't just use the modal's click event to close it.

Here is my current code:

```
<modal #addNewClassModal>
    <modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>  Add a new class</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-content>

      <div>
        <add-new-class (closeModal)="finishAddingNewClass($event)">
        </add-new-class>
      </div>

    </modal-content>
</modal>
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the modals `close()` method to rely on the boolean. 
I've tried putting `closeModal="addNewClassModal.close()"` in different places and switching around the syntax but its not working and I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to `addNewClassModal` to your `AddNewClass` component:

```
<add-new-class [modal]="addNewClassModal">
</add-new-class>
```

And in your `AddNewClass` component add `Input()` for modal:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/modal';

@Input()
modal: ModalDirective; // you can also set type to any instead of ModalDirective
```

Then in your component you can close modal with `hide()` function:

```
this.modal.hide();
```

Comment: But won't this mess up the component for use in the first case, where it is not contained in a modal?
I am trying to import the same component for both cases because it will be necessary in multiple places on the site.

Comment: @DónalFlanagan It won't, `Input()` values are optional, not mandatory.

Comment: It worked! I didn't realise Input() events were not mandatory. Now I simply call it in two different ways. (1)  `<add-new-class  redirectUrl='classes'> </add-new-class>`   and  (2) inside the modal `<add-new-class  [modal]="addNewClassModal2"></add-new-class>`
Then, when the user clicks _Cancel_ I call the method  `(click)="onFinishAddingNewClass()"`, which exits the modal according to the input type.

Comment: @DónalFlanagan Great, I'm glad it helped. Please consider marking my answer as accepted and upvoting it if it helped. :-) (both are on the left side of the answer)